# Не работает инициализация БД

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, flyway

Я инициализирую базу через flyway, после чего, если приложение запущено локально, мне нужно накатить скрипты с тестовыми данными. Flyway отрабатывает нормально, но с тестовыми скриптами некоторые сложности - они не работают. Проперти инициализации выглядят так:

```
# data source properties
# ��������� �� - ��. DatasourceConfig

database.port=5482

#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:${database.port}}/
#spring.datasource.username=postgres
#spring.datasource.password=

spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.character=utf-8
spring.datasource.embedded-directory = target
#spring.datasource.schema=classpath:db/migration/common/V001__schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:db/migration/dev/init.sql

# JPA properties
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false

# migration properties
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.check-location=false
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.baseline-version=0
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/common
```

По логике инициализации, должны выполниться скрипты, доступные по переменной

```
spring.datasource.data=classpath:db/migration/dev/init.sql
```

Но база пустая.
Подскажите, что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для накатывания демо данных я использую тот же Flyway и отдельный Spring профиль (например, **dev**): в одной папке лежат общие скрипты (для разработки и для прода), в другой - скрипты с демо данными. Примерно так:

```
/db
  /migration
    /common
      V1.1__schema.sql
      V2.0__some_migration.sql
    /dev
      V1.2__demo_data.sql
```

Файлы настроек, общий и dev:

application.yml:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    locations: classpath:db/migration/common
```

application-dev.yml:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    locations: classpath:db/migration/common,classpath:db/migration/dev
```

Тут хитрый момент с версионированием файлов миграции - если указать подверсию (через точку или подчеркивание), то Flyway будет накатывать скрипты в нужном порядке независимо от каталогов, в которых они хранятся: 1.1, 1.2, 2.0 и т.д

Подробнее:

- [Execute Flyway Database Migrations on Startup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup)
- [Versioned Migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#versioned-migrations)
- [Naming](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#naming)

P.S. Насчет свойства `spring.datasource.data` могу предположить, что Бут его не использует, если активирован Flyway.